Consumer Widget + AsyncNotifierProviderFamily + FamilyAsyncNotifier Leading to Continous Unregulated Widget Rebuilds and State Updates
I am trying to create a simple FamilyAsyncNotifier for my Profile Consumer widget. However, for some reason, the state is continuously getting rebuilt and the build method in my FamilyAsyncNotifier keeps on getting executed.
What are best practices when working with this sort of thing?
// TheTime\frontend\lib\src\features\profile\presentation\profile_screen.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:frontend/src/features/profile/presentation/profile_screen_controller_wp.dart';


class ProfileScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({super.key, required this.userId, required this.isAdmin});

  final String userId;
  final bool isAdmin;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final controllerParams = ProfileScreenControllerParams(userId, isAdmin);
    final profileState = ref.watch(profileScreenControllerProvider(controllerParams));
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: OverflowBox(
          maxWidth: 80,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Handle settings icon pressed
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Handle share icon pressed
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        title: profileState.when(
          data: (profile) { 
            return Center(
              child: Text('${profile?.firstName ?? ''} ${profile?.lastName ?? ''}'),
            );
          },
          loading: () {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
          error: (error, stackTrace) {
            return const Center(child: Text('Error'));
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.message),
            onPressed: () {
              // Handle messages icon pressed
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: profileState.when(
        data: (profile) {
          if (profile != null) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(width: 16),
                    const CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 40,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 16),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Handle friends pressed
                            },
                            child: const Text('Friends'),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Handle followers pressed
                            },
                            child: const Text('Followers'),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Handle following pressed
                            },
                            child: const Text('Following'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Text(
                    'Username: ${profile.username}',
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Text(
                    profile.biography ?? '',
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Handle create program pressed
                          },
                          child: const Text('Create Program'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 16),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Handle edit profile pressed
                          },
                          child: const Text('Edit Profile'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: Text('User not found'));
          }
        },
        loading: () {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) {
          return const Center(child: Text('Error occurred'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// TheTime\\frontend\\lib\\src\\features\\profile\\presentation\\profile_screen_controller_wp.dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:frontend/src/features/profile/data/profile_repository_wp.dart';
import 'package:frontend/src/features/profile/domain/profile_model.dart';
import 'package:frontend/src/features/authentication/data/auth_repository_providers.dart';

//TODO: Figure out how to dispose of this appropriately.
//TODO: Figure out how to handle multiple controller/controller-provider instances simulataneouly. Probably another collections provider. 
//TODO: Above todos are kept for later.
//TODO: Need to add retry mechanisms and routes different flows depending on exception.

final profileScreenControllerProvider = AsyncNotifierProviderFamily<ProfileScreenController, Profile?, ProfileScreenControllerParams>(() {
  return ProfileScreenController();
});

class ProfileScreenControllerParams {
  final String userId;
  final bool isAdmin;
  ProfileScreenControllerParams(this.userId, this.isAdmin);
}

class ProfileScreenController extends FamilyAsyncNotifier<Profile?, ProfileScreenControllerParams> { //Remeber that ProfileScreenControllerParams is arg.

  @override //TODO: Consider storing references to obej
  FutureOr<Profile?> build(ProfileScreenControllerParams arg) async { //TODO this is getting stuck in some kind of infinite loop. Is there something wrong with my family implementation? //This is very bootleg!    
    return await getProfileById(arg.userId);    
  }

  Future<Profile?> getProfileById(String userId) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    final profileRepository = ref.read(profileRepositoryProvider);
    try {
      final profile = profileRepository.getProfileById(userId);
      if (profile != null) {
        state = AsyncValue.data(profile);
        return profile;
      } else {
        await profileRepository.fetchRemoteProfileById(userId);
        final fetchedProfile = profileRepository.getProfileById(userId);
        if (fetchedProfile != null) {
          state = AsyncValue.data(fetchedProfile);
          return fetchedProfile;
        } else {
          state = AsyncValue.error(Exception('Profile not found'), StackTrace.current);
          return null;
        }
      }
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, stackTrace);
      return null;
    }
  }
}

I have tried to return parameters directly like
final profileScreenControllerProvider = AsyncNotifierProviderFamily<ProfileScreenController, Profile?, ProfileScreenControllerParams>(
  (ref, params) {
    return ProfileScreenController(ref, params);
  },
  dependencies: [profileRepositoryProvider],
).autoDispose();```

But AsyncNotifierProviderFamily does not want you to pass parameters when creating instances of the FamilyAsyncNotifier.

I want to avoid using generator as I want to manually implement my providers.


class ProfileScreenControllerParams {
  final String userId;
  final bool isAdmin;

  ProfileScreenControllerParams(this.userId, this.isAdmin);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ProfileScreenControllerParams &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          userId == other.userId &&
          isAdmin == other.isAdmin;

  @override
  int get hashCode => userId.hashCode ^ isAdmin.hashCode;
}

You have to identify the params you pass into the family so that it knows when it actually changes.
